# Application Theming

Tags: jquery, html, css, themes

I'm designing an application that'd require different themes. By 'theme' I mean the colors and logo. Is using jQuery themeroller the only option or is there any easier solution to generate themes by providing colors and images?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to give the body (or a div that wraps everything) a css class to indicate the theme.

Then you can specify colours and background images based on theme class.

For example

```
.theme1 .thingy { color: #eee; }
.theme2 .thingy { color: red; }
```

You could put theme1 and theme2 definitions in separate files if you so wish.

Doing it this way means the theme can be swapped using client-side javascript just by changing the body's class.

Answer (score 0):

Themeroller is just a way to customize specific classes.  The jQueryUI widgets use pre-defined classes.  Themeroller themes just define those classes.  You can just as easily develop a second stylesheet for your application, that re-defines the classes you've used.